# Как узнать, как долго будут вычисляться функция из long.MaxValue шагов?

Tags: c#, .net, time-complexity

Час назад я написал такой код, чтобы проверить правильность решенной мною задачи:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i < long.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum -= 1.0 / (double)i;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += 1.0 / (double)i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Ln(2) = " + Math.Log(2));

        Console.WriteLine("Our sum: " + sum);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Но до сих пор я не получил результат.. Как я понимаю long.MaxValue шагов это слишком много, но это 20!, что не так уж и много, ибо я был уведомлен, что сейчас компьютеры и 150! шагов могут вычислить. Но все же, как долго еще будет выполняться мой код, как можно это узнать?

Comment: так выполните цикл 1 раз и замерьте время, и потом просто результат умножьте на 20!

Comment: а если серьезно, то время выполнения программы зависит от многих факторов, начиная от скорости и типа процессора и заканчивая фазой луны. Потому точное время выполнения вы не узнаете пока не дождетесь результата

Comment: Код который написан можете не ждать, его даже ваши правнуки не дождутся. К тому же точность `double` иссякнет гораздо раньше, так что такой длинный цикл вообще ни чего не даст кроме обогрева атмосферы. Лучше определитесь с необходимой точностью вычислений и используйте цикл с условием выхода при достижении заданной точности.

Comment: Засеките минуту, поставьте брейкпоинт и посмотрите чему равен i, потом просто разделите long.MaxValue на это число и получите число минут. Кстати, эта задача очень хорошо распараллеливается, хорошо бы этим воспользоваться — сократите время в n раз.

Comment: Ну и можно выиграть немного заменив приращение в цикле на 2 и вычисляя на каждой итерации `sum += 1.0 / i - 1.0 / (i + 1);` Также можно проверять новое значение sum на равенство с предыдущим и когда это условие выполнится — досрочно прервать цикл (как вам сказали выше, будет достигнут предел точности double)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас топовый процессор из **8 ядер** с частотой **4 ГГц**. Такой проц может выдавать 8*4*1024*1024*1024 = **2^35 тактов в секунду**.

Ваш цикл будет включать `long.MaxValue = 2^63` итераций. Каждая итерация включает в себя:

1. остаток по модулю
2. проверку условия
3. деление
4. вычитание

Зажмурив глаза, представим, что на одну такую итерацию будет уходить 4 такта процессора. Т.е. на обсчет вашего цикла уйдет не меньше **2^65 тактов**.

Давайте считать, всего **2^65 тактов**, скорость **2^35 такта в секунду**, получаем **2^30 секунд**. Это где-то 34 года =)

---

Для того, что вы пытаетесь посчитать, существует формула:

[image: Формула]

Хотя зачем программисту учить математику...

Comment: ещё есть операции в самом цикле `i < long.MaxValue; i++` + переход :)

Comment: 68 лет! 
Да уж, ужасно..
Да математику то я учил, это я просто так сверял по-быстренькому ряды, которые были в видео по математике :)

Comment: На самом деле результат был получен еще на i < 100000, но просто хотелось большей и большей точности.